# SVG filled path - if it loops back over itself the overlap is not filled

Tags: svg

I maintain a drawing tool written in flash that saves its data for the highlighter tool as a series of points describing the outline of a thick filled freehand/point-to-point line. For example if the user drew a horizontal line, the path would be a sequence of points from left to right, then a line down 10 pixels, the same sequence of points in reverse to get back to 10px below the origin, then he path is closed

Another tool periodically rasterizes flash's data by converting the json list of points to an svg path. The path command is like "M 123,456 l 1,2 3,5 -2,-5..." and describes the complete outer edge of the shape. There's no stroke, and the fill is opacity 0.4

I've noticed that if the user has drawn a single line that overlaps itself, like the greek symbol alpha, the overlapping portion is not filled. I was expecting it to become more opaque as would a real highlighter.

Is this behaviour by design in SVG? Or could it be a bug in the library i use? If by design, what alternative tactic can i use to render a part opaque highlighter line that progressively becomes more opaque if it crosses over itself?

I should note that two separate lines (svg doc contains two path elements that cross over) drawn over each other DO become more opaque as expected, its just if its a single path element, this odd behaviour occurs

Here is an example SVG document demonstrating the behaviour. It can be visualized on something like http://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.htm (paste the code into the top text box and click the magnifying glass icon. Requires a browser that understands SVG)

```html
    <svg width="680" height="465" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g>
        <path d="M 283,29 l -2,2 -1,1 -5,4 -5,4 -4,3 -4,2 -3,2 -4,3 -6,3 -4,2 -5,3 -6,5 -3,2 -4,2 -1,1 -5,2 -4,3 -4,2 -3,1 -3,2 -3,2 -4,1 -8,3 -3,1 -5,1 -6,1 -1,0 -5,1 -4,0 -5,0 -6,1 -6,0 -7,0 -10,0 -7,0 -7,0 -5,0 -5,0 -9,0 -2,0 -3,0 -8,0 -3,0 -6,0 -4,0 -4,0 -3,-1 -3,-1 -2,-2 -2,-1 -3,-4 0,-1 -2,-3 -2,-4 -1,-2 -1,-3 -1,-5 0,-6 0,-4 0,-4 0,-4 0,-5 0,-5 0,-4 1,-4 3,-4 3,-4 2,-3 2,-3 2,-2 1,-1 3,-1 2,-1 2,-1 8,-3 7,-1 5,-1 4,0 3,0 3,0 2,0 2,0 2,0 2,0 3,0 2,0 3,0 2,0 5,0 3,0 1,0 2,0 3,1 4,2 3,0 2,2 4,2 4,2 3,1 2,2 2,2 3,2 4,3 3,3 2,2 3,3 2,3 2,2 2,3 1,3 2,3 2,3 3,3 2,3 1,3 2,3 2,3 2,3 2,3 1,3 1,3 2,2 2,2 2,3 1,3 3,3 2,3 1,2 2,1 1,2 2,1 2,2 3,1 2,1 2,2 2,1 3,1 3,1 2,2 3,1 4,2 4,2 3,1 3,1 3,1 3,0 2,1 2,1 2,0 4,1 4,1 4,0 3,0 3,0 4,0 2,0 4,0 3,0 1,0 2,0 3,0 3,0 2,0 2,0 3,0 2,0 2,0 1,0 1,-1 1,0 2,-1 2,0 2,-1 1,0 1,-1 1,0 1,-1 1,0 1,0 0,25 -1,0 -1,0 -1,1 -1,0 -1,1 -1,0 -2,1 -2,0 -2,1 -1,0 -1,1 -1,0 -2,0 -2,0 -3,0 -2,0 -2,0 -3,0 -3,0 -2,0 -1,0 -3,0 -4,0 -2,0 -4,0 -3,0 -3,0 -4,0 -4,-1 -4,-1 -2,0 -2,-1 -2,-1 -3,0 -3,-1 -3,-1 -3,-1 -4,-2 -4,-2 -3,-1 -2,-2 -3,-1 -3,-1 -2,-1 -2,-2 -2,-1 -3,-1 -2,-2 -2,-1 -1,-2 -2,-1 -1,-2 -2,-3 -3,-3 -1,-3 -2,-3 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-3 -1,-3 -2,-3 -2,-3 -2,-3 -2,-3 -1,-3 -2,-3 -3,-3 -2,-3 -2,-3 -1,-3 -2,-3 -2,-2 -2,-3 -3,-3 -2,-2 -3,-3 -4,-3 -3,-2 -2,-2 -2,-2 -3,-1 -4,-2 -4,-2 -2,-2 -3,0 -4,-2 -3,-1 -2,0 -1,0 -3,0 -5,0 -2,0 -3,0 -2,0 -3,0 -2,0 -2,0 -2,0 -2,0 -3,0 -3,0 -4,0 -5,1 -7,1 -8,3 -2,1 -2,1 -3,1 -1,1 -2,2 -2,3 -2,3 -3,4 -3,4 -1,4 0,4 0,5 0,5 0,4 0,4 0,4 0,6 1,5 1,3 1,2 2,4 2,3 0,1 3,4 2,1 2,2 3,1 3,1 4,0 4,0 6,0 3,0 8,0 3,0 2,0 9,0 5,0 5,0 7,0 7,0 10,0 7,0 6,0 6,-1 5,0 4,0 5,-1 1,0 6,-1 5,-1 3,-1 8,-3 4,-1 3,-2 3,-2 3,-1 4,-2 4,-3 5,-2 1,-1 4,-2 3,-2 6,-5 5,-3 4,-2 6,-3 4,-3 3,-2 4,-2 4,-3 5,-4 5,-4 1,-1 2,-2" style="stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; fill: #0000CC; fill-opacity: 0.4; fill-rule: evenodd; stroke: none" />
    
        <path d="M 583,29 l -2,2 -1,1 -5,4 -5,4 -4,3 -4,2 -3,2 -4,3 -6,3 -4,2 -5,3 -6,5 -3,2 -4,2 -1,1 -5,2 -4,3 -4,2 -3,1 -3,2 -3,2 -4,1 -8,3 -3,1 -5,1 -6,1 -1,0 -5,1 -4,0 -5,0 -6,1 -6,0 -7,0 -10,0 -7,0 -7,0 -5,0 -5,0 -9,0 -2,0 -3,0 -8,0 -3,0 -6,0 -4,0 -4,0 -3,-1 -3,-1 -2,-2 -2,-1 -3,-4 0,-1 -2,-3 -2,-4 -1,-2 -1,-3 -1,-5 0,-6 0,-4 0,-4 0,-4 0,-5 0,-5 0,-4 1,-4 3,-4 3,-4 2,-3 2,-3 2,-2 1,-1 3,-1 2,-1 2,-1 8,-3 7,-1 5,-1 4,0 3,0 3,0 2,0 2,0 2,0 2,0 3,0 2,0 3,0 2,0 5,0 3,0 1,0 2,0 3,1 4,2 3,0 2,2 4,2 4,2 3,1 2,2 2,2 3,2 4,3 3,3 2,2 3,3 2,3 2,2 2,3 1,3 2,3 2,3 3,3 2,3 1,3 2,3 2,3 2,3 2,3 1,3 1,3 2,2 2,2 2,3 1,3 3,3 2,3 1,2 2,1 1,2 2,1 2,2 3,1 2,1 2,2 2,1 3,1 3,1 2,2 3,1 4,2 4,2 3,1 3,1 3,1 3,0 2,1 2,1 2,0 4,1 4,1 4,0 3,0 3,0 4,0 2,0 4,0 3,0 1,0 2,0 3,0 3,0 2,0 2,0 3,0 2,0 2,0 1,0 1,-1 1,0 2,-1 2,0 2,-1 1,0 1,-1 1,0 1,-1 1,0 1,0 0,25 -1,0 -1,0 -1,1 -1,0 -1,1 -1,0 -2,1 -2,0 -2,1 -1,0 -1,1 -1,0 -2,0 -2,0 -3,0 -2,0 -2,0 -3,0 -3,0 -2,0 -1,0 -3,0 -4,0 -2,0 -4,0 -3,0 -3,0 -4,0 -4,-1 -4,-1 -2,0 -2,-1 -2,-1 -3,0 -3,-1 -3,-1 -3,-1 -4,-2 -4,-2 -3,-1 -2,-2 -3,-1 -3,-1 -2,-1 -2,-2 -2,-1 -3,-1 -2,-2 -2,-1 -1,-2 -2,-1 -1,-2 -2,-3 -3,-3 -1,-3 -2,-3 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-3 -1,-3 -2,-3 -2,-3 -2,-3 -2,-3 -1,-3 -2,-3 -3,-3 -2,-3 -2,-3 -1,-3 -2,-3 -2,-2 -2,-3 -3,-3 -2,-2 -3,-3 -4,-3 -3,-2 -2,-2 -2,-2 -3,-1 -4,-2 -4,-2 -2,-2 -3,0 -4,-2 -3,-1 -2,0 -1,0 -3,0 -5,0 -2,0 -3,0 -2,0 -3,0 -2,0 -2,0 -2,0 -2,0 -3,0 -3,0 -4,0 -5,1 -7,1 -8,3 -2,1 -2,1 -3,1 -1,1 -2,2 -2,3 -2,3 -3,4 -3,4 -1,4 0,4 0,5 0,5 0,4 0,4 0,4 0,6 1,5 1,3 1,2 2,4 2,3 0,1 3,4 2,1 2,2 3,1 3,1 4,0 4,0 6,0 3,0 8,0 3,0 2,0 9,0 5,0 5,0 7,0 7,0 10,0 7,0 6,0 6,-1 5,0 4,0 5,-1 1,0 6,-1 5,-1 3,-1 8,-3 4,-1 3,-2 3,-2 3,-1 4,-2 4,-3 5,-2 1,-1 4,-2 3,-2 6,-5 5,-3 4,-2 6,-3 4,-3 3,-2 4,-2 4,-3 5,-4 5,-4 1,-1 2,-2" style="stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; fill: #0000CC; fill-opacity: 0.4; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: none" />
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Regarding the comments: The doc essentially draws two alpha symbols using a filled path, though the `fill-rule` of each symbol differs. There isn't an appreciable difference in the appearance, though for more complex shapes that cross back over themselves several times there is a difference in output - all examples fail to replicate a highlighter pen that darkens whenever the filled area passes back over an already-filled area of the same path

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty

Comment: It's not odd behaviour. It is by design. It is the reason why it is possible to make, for example, a doughnut shape.  Paths that overlap themselves can make holes.  If you want to modify that behaviour, there is an attribute for that (the one that Robert linked to).

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the pointer - I wasn't able to use it to solve the problem (but I've included a verifiable example of the problem occurring if you'd like to take a look)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau do you have any comment on whether this method of using a path (that is a forward set of points, then a vertical offset, then the same points in reverse, then another vertical to close) is a suitable method to replicate a highlighter? I wasn't able to make things look correct by changing the fill rule.. So I now wonder if there's an alternative strategy I should be employing for drawing a filled point to point outline in svg.. I considered rendering the path as individual polygons -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492478 seemed to agree this is a way it can be done simply

Comment: You can't draw a shape darker by "ovepainting" by design in SVG. You'd need to use two separate shapes.

Comment: Thanks robert, i'll give a try at converting my freehand path of 100 points into 100 individual poly shapes and see how it works out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your problem now. Unfortunately `fill-rule: nonzero` doesn't help in your case because your path doesn't just self-intersect (which would normally be fine), but it also crosses over itself on the left hand side. That messes up the fill rule "nonzero" algorithm.

There isn't really a simple solution either.  The best I can suggest is to detect when the highlighter path hits a horizontal inflection point (ie changes direction horizontally) and split the path into two paths (or sub-paths) at that point.

Comment: I did this, and it worked out. For my particular path, I scanned all the points' X values and worked out whether the path was going left or right at that point. I compared this direction to the previous noted direction, and if I detected a change in direction I started a new SVG path. It works out because my highlighter is an infinitely thin vertical line, X pixels high, so checnges in vertical direction are irrelevant from an overpaint perspective. This new tactic has allowed me to minimise the number of SVG paths but have them overpaint and darken perfectly. Thanks for the tip!