# SVG stroke overlaps disappear

Tags: svg, safari

If I make a tight circle using path and a big stroke around it, the overlap of the stroke area on itself becomes white. It's important for me to programmatically generate these strokes for any paths without these white overlaps. It's also important for me to have any size of a stroke working well without holes.

```html
<svg width="1366" height="1024" viewBox="0 0 1366 1024" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path id="rgb-template blink" d="M788.563 290.064C796.281 290.064 802.537 280.447 802.537 268.584C802.537 256.721 796.281 247.104 788.563 247.104C780.845 247.104 774.589 256.721 774.589 268.584C774.589 280.447 780.845 290.064 788.563 290.064Z" class="blink" stroke="#0F0" stroke-width="151" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="red"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942666/space-between-svg-stroke-and-fill somewhat similar question

Comment: Curve rendering with very large strokes is often buggy. Better to use smaller strokes and fill the shapes instead.

Comment: @MichaelMullany there's a reason for me to use small curves with large strokes and it's pretty hard to avoid it (automatically generate shapes from desired strokes). Though I've already found an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that adding  `stroke-linecap="round" style="stroke-dasharray: 1000, 1000;"` fixes the issue by introducing virtual dashes

```html
    <svg width="1366" height="1024" viewBox="0 0 1366 1024" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path id="rgb-template blink" d="M788.563 290.064C796.281 290.064 802.537 280.447 802.537 268.584C802.537 256.721 796.281 247.104 788.563 247.104C780.845 247.104 774.589 256.721 774.589 268.584C774.589 280.447 780.845 290.064 788.563 290.064Z" class="blink" stroke="#0F0" stroke-width="151" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="red" style="stroke-dasharray: 1000, 1000; stroke-dashoffset: 0;"></path>
    <path id="rgb-template blink" d="M788.563 290.064C796.281 290.064 802.537 280.447 802.537 268.584C802.537 256.721 796.281 247.104 788.563 247.104C780.845 247.104 774.589 256.721 774.589 268.584C774.589 280.447 780.845 290.064 788.563 290.064Z" class="blink" stroke="#0F0" stroke-width="151" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="red"></path>
    </svg>
```